# Prove that for all $n \gt 1$ $\lim_{r \to 1} \frac {r^n-1}{r-1} = n$

Tags: limits, induction

Prove that for all numbers $n \gt 1$  $\lim_{r \to 1} \frac {r^n-1}{r-1} = n$

I think induction will work for this, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I have the base $n=1$ case because $\lim_{r \to 1} \frac {r^1-1}{r-1} = 1$ holds, then by induction hypothesis I would say it hold for $n$, then I just need to show it hold for $(n+1)$, which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: One way is to notice that the limit is the definition of the derivative of $r^n$ evaluated at $r=1$.

Comment: If you want to use induction then you can use $\frac{r^{n+1} -  1}{r-1} = r^{n} + \frac{r^{n} - 1}{r-1}$ so if $s_n = \lim_{r\to 1} \frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$ then $s_{n+1} = 1 + s_n$. Now show using induction that $s_n = n$.

Comment: Do you mean all numbers or all positive integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $(r^n-1)=(r^{n-1}+\cdots+r+1)(r-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(r)
=r^n
$.
$f'(r)
=nr^{n-1}
$.

But
$f'(r)
=\lim_{x \to r} \frac{f(x)-f(r)}{x-r}
=\lim_{x \to r} \frac{x^n-r^n}{x-r}
$
so
$n
=f'(1)
=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}
$